# How to get object sender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to send the `object sender` when I click to a button.

Previously my event click doesn't fire but now it is making my code like these:

```
 public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static bool enable = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }
            else if(enable)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }    
        }
```

this is the event that change the `DynamicButton` and start everything:

```
protected void DButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            enable = true;
            DynamicButton();
        }
```

here's where I start the creation of the dynamically buttons:

```
protected void DynamicButton()
        {
            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {
                LinkButton newButton = new LinkButton();
                newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.Text = team;
                newButton.CommandArgument = "ENG";

                newButton.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

                pan1.Controls.Add(newButton);

                newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";

            }
        }
```

And here's where the created buttons start his event

```
protected void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ModalGood();", true);
            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfToolsOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.TEAM == "516" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var ToolArea = ListOfToolsOk.Select(x => x.TEAM);
            Grv_Eng.DataSource = ListOfToolsOk;
            Grv_Eng.DataBind();
        }
```

My questions are

**How can I get the event `sender` of `DButton` to send into DynamicButton to change these?**

I mean:

```
Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
var name = Btn_clic.Text;
```

I need the event sender of `DButton` to change this

`List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == CHANGE THIS -> "ENG" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();`

`newButton.CommandArgument = CHANGE THIS -> "ENG";`

those are from `DynamicButton`

**And how can I get the event `sender` of the Dynamic button created and how can I get the event from DButton to send into `NewButton_Click`?**

I mean too

```
Button Btnclick = (Button)sender;
var team = Btnclick.Text;
string name = Btnclick.CommandArgument;
```

and to change this one that are from `newButton_Click`:

`List<Data.Area> ListOfToolsOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == CHANGE THIS -> "ENG" && x.TEAM == CHANGE THIS -> "516" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still working on your problem.  But I did get your event to work.  Please let me know if this helps, and I will continue to assist.  Put a breakpoint in the beginning of newButton_Click to see that it breaks here now.  Credit so far to internet post.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace List
{
    public class ListUsers
    {
        public List<Data.Area> AreaList()
        {
            var list = new List<Data.Area>();
            Data.Area area1 = new Data.Area { AREA = "ENG", STANDBY = 0, TEAM = "team1" };
            Data.Area area2 = new Data.Area { AREA = "ENG", STANDBY = 0, TEAM = "team2" };
            Data.Area area3 = new Data.Area { AREA = "area3", STANDBY = 3, TEAM = "team3" };
            list.Add(area1);
            list.Add(area2);
            list.Add(area3);
            return list;
        }
    }
}

namespace Data
{
    public class Area
    {
        public string AREA { get; set; }
        public int STANDBY { get; set; }
        public string TEAM { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //BTW static variable are shared across multiple users of your web site
        static bool enable = false;

        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            //NEED TO set event listener in oninit everytime
            DynamicButton();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //DynamicButton();

            }
            else if (enable)
            {
                //DynamicButton();
            }
        }

        protected void DynamicButton()
        {
            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {
                LinkButton newButton = new LinkButton();
                newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.Text = team;
                newButton.CommandArgument = "ENG";

                newButton.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

                pan1.Controls.Add(newButton);

                newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
            }
        }

        public void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ModalGood();", true);
            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfToolsOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.TEAM == "516" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var ToolArea = ListOfToolsOk.Select(x => x.TEAM);
            Grv_Eng.DataSource = ListOfToolsOk;
            Grv_Eng.DataBind();
        }

        protected void DButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            enable = true;
            DynamicButton();
        }
    }
}
```